# Makefile target to build all matching files at once

Tags: makefile

We have two targets for building all of our JS, one takes the full list of files and passes it off to the transpile script and the other takes only the changed file and passes it off to the transpile script. The issue is that if you have `n` changed files, it executes the matching target one at a time for each file.

The current targets:

```
.PHONY: build-all
build-all:
    FILE_LIST="$(RAWJSFILES)" ./scripts/transpile.js

$(BUILD)/app/%.js: $(SRC)/app/%.js
    FILE_LIST="$(SRC)/app/$*.js" ./scripts/transpile.js
```

Is it possible for a target to get all matching changed files which can then be passed to the transpile script so that it is only executed once? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say exactly how you want this to work, and I'm not familiar with JavaScript hacking or "transpile" so I can't guess.

But if you want a target that always runs the script on any files that have been changed since the last time it was run, you can use something like:

```
ALLFILES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/app/*.js

build-all: $(ALLFILES)
        FILE_LIST="$?" ./scripts/transpile.js
        @touch $@
```

See [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for a discussion of `$?`.

There are issues with this, but since your problem wasn't well-defined it's not clear whether they'll affect you.

Comment: Excellent thanks this works exactly how I was hoping it would. I had figured that using `$?` was the answer but I hadn't thought of using a canary file as the comparitor.